# Added column in R not found

Tags: r

I want to train a linear model in R. Therefore, I want to take the mean of one of the explanatory variables. I am using the following code to add the column mean_of_price to my table:

```
prices2 = subset(prices, type == "Apartment")
prices2$mean_of_size = mean(prices2$size)
prices2
```

If I print prices2, then the column mean_of_price is visible. However, if I train a linear model with `lm(price~type+mean_of_size+size), data = prices2)` then I'm getting the following error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'mean_of_size' not found

What is the problem here?

Comment: Is it because the `)` is before the `data` i.e. you may try `lm(price~type+mean_of_size+size, data = prices2)`

Comment: I'm sorry, something went wrong with pasting my code. I have the ')' after data = prices2, so that is not the problem

Comment: Can you try on a fresh R session

Comment: I did, and now it's saying that object 'price' cannot be found....I checked the table and the columns are definitely in there.

Comment: Can you show the `dput(prices2)` or `str(prices2)`

Comment: 'data.frame': 28 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ size    : num  11.1 12.7 14.9 15.8 10.7 16.7 12.2 15.2 13.9 14.4 ...
 $ price      : num  19.5 23.8 39 47.6 18.8 53.6 20.6 39.6 30.7 32.7 ...
 $ type        : chr  "apartment" "apartment" "apartment" "apartment" ...
 $ mean_of_size: num  14.6 14.6 14.6 14.6 14.6 ...

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Is there any leading/lagging spaces in column names i.e. try `names(prices2) <- trimws(names(prices2))`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as well. I don't understand why object 'price' cannot be found since it's there if I print out prices2

Comment: can you update your post with the `dput(prices2)` so that I can test it

Comment: structure(list(size = c(11.1, 12.7, 14.9, 15.8, 10.7, 16.7, 
12.2, 15.2, 13.9, 14.4, 16.6, 12.8), 
type = c("apartment", "apartment", "apartment", "apartment", 
    "apartment", "apartment", "apartment", "apartment", "apartment", "apartment", "apartment", "apartment"), mean_of_size = c(14.6357142857143, 
    14.6357142857143, 14.6357142857143, 14.6357142857143, 14.6357142857143, 
    14.6357142857143, 14.6357142857143, 14.6357142857143, 14.6357142857143, 
    14.6357142857143, 14.6357142857143, 14.6357142857143)), row.names = 32:49, class = "data.frame")

I had to cut it due to length

Comment: In the dput output, there is no column named `price` `names(prices2)#
[1] "size"         "type"         "mean_of_size"`

Comment: @Robin please update your question by editing it to add this dput data. You had to cut it because comments aren't intended to post large chunks of code that are part of your question.

Comment: Also, if there is no extra `)` in your code, edit your question to fix that issue. It is impossible to know what your issue is if there are many others in how you are presenting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with the `)`

```
lm(price~type+mean_of_size+size, data = prices2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @akrun said, the `)` isn't helping anything:

```
lm(price~type+mean_of_size+size), data = prices2)
```

should be

```
lm(price~type+mean_of_size+size, data = prices2)
```

But also note that

```
prices2$mean_of_size = mean(prices2$size)
```

Is assigning the same value to the entire column. Just to be sure that is what you want.

Now that you say that is what you want, note that your model isn't going to be able to use that information in any way. If every value is the same for every row, there is no information there, and you will likely get `NA`

Simple example:

```
x<-rnorm(100) # 100 random values pulled from a normal distribution
y<-rnorm(100) # 100 random values pulled from a normal distribution
z<-rep(5,100) # the same value 100 times

summary(lm(y~x+z))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + z)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.44429 -0.71534 -0.07313  0.48823  2.44896 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -0.1626     0.1027  -1.583    0.117
x             0.1636     0.1037   1.578    0.118
z                 NA         NA      NA       NA
```

Comment: The same value for each row is indeed what I want